# Url Slug should be localized?

Tags: url, seo, multilingual, slug

I am creating a multilingual website in which I am using  URL Slug.

According to SEO point of view should I use URL Slug in multiple languages?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should have separate URLs for each language. For example:

```
example.com/en/sport and example.com/de/sport
```

Google recommends having **one** of these structures:

1. Separate domains
2. Separate subdomains
3. Separate folders
4. URL parameters

I would recommend using URL parameters only if other options are not possible.

[In this link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html) you can find pros and cons for all these options.